# Update several values in node js mysql2

Tags: mysql, node.js

If I do this to assign a dummy name:

```
data = [Number(db_result[0].id), String("asdfa.jpg")];
console.log(data);
conn.query("UPDATE details SET name = 'asdfa.jpg' WHERE id = ?", data).then(console.log("Everything fine"));
```

it works and the DB is being updated.

But if I try to update the *name* with the correct variable,:

```
conn.query("UPDATE mstat_mails SET screenshot_name = ? WHERE id = ?", data).then(console.log("Everything fine"));
```

I receive an error

```
[ 7479, 'asdfa.jpg' ]
Everything fine
Unhandled rejection Error: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'asdfa.jpg'
at PromiseConnection.query (/home/hpn/puppeteer/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:92:22)
at main (/home/hpn/puppeteer/test.js:97:8)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?